# Python Value Error when attempting to remove an element from a list

Tags: python, list, valueerror

This program is suppose to take a text file and convert its contents into a list where each element is a line from the original text file. from there I want to be able to see if certain websites that are in another list are contained with in an element, if so remove that element from the list. I keep getting a ValueError

```
with open(hosts_temp, 'r+') as file1:
     content = file1.read() 
     x = content.splitlines() #convert contents of file1 in to a list of strings.

     for element in x:
         for site in websites_list:
             if site in element:
                 x.remove(element)      
             else:
                 pass
```

Here is the error im getting:

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: the error message doesn't match your code, which removes from a list while iterating...

Comment: I suppose you need to `break` when found & removed, but even like this it wont work. Rebuild the list with a list comprehension instead

Comment: it can be a case of duplicates as well. If your site is present in the element multiple times and only once in x. Even then, this error can prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are removing the line from the line array then trying to access it again.

For example if you have a website list of

```
website_list = ["google","facebook"]
```

and your x (list of lines) is

```
["First sentence","Second sentence containing google","Last sentence"]
```

Looking at this loop

```
for site in websites_list:
```

You would remove the second sentence from x because you matched google. However, you would also then try to check if the second sentence contained "facebook". Because you already removed the second sentence from your x list, you will get an error.

I would **recommend** reading the file **line by line** instead of grabbing all the lines at once. If it is a line without a website name, then add it to a valid list collection.

Another pythonic way to solve this is to use list comprehension
if your input is not large

```
with open(hosts_temp, 'r+') as file1:
 content = file1.read() 
 x = content.splitlines()
 x = [line for line in x if all(w not in line for w in websites_list)]
```

It is good practice to be very careful when iterating over an collection and adding/deleting elements along the way.

Comment: you still are removing the element from the list while iterating over it. If 2 elements to remove follow, you're skipping the second one

Comment: You are completely correct. Fixed with an pythonic alternative